# Checkboxes linked to cells, looping through the value is always seen as 'True' in code but visible correctly on spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I linked the spreadsheet activeX checkbox controls to the cell in which they reside.  Checked-true, unchecked-false as expected.  However, this is not useful b/c the code sees them ALL as true.  Ideas why this is happening?

Stripped down code:

```
    Set r = Range("G2") checkboxes for each sheet
    r.Activate
    For i = 7 To 26
        r = Cells(2, i).Activate
        
            MsgBox r.Value
    Next i
```

I expect False for the unchecked columns (visible on the spreadsheet) but get true with r each time for each cell in the 2nd row in the range.

Comment: Get rid of `r = Cells(2, i).Activate` and use `MsgBox Cells(2, i).Value`

Comment: Thanks.  If I wanted to update the range inside the loop, is it necessary to 'set' it each time-code is dumbed down.  I'm having trouble with the concept.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your end goal is, but I'd use a `For Each` loop here: `Dim r As Range`, `Set r = Range("G2:Z2")`, `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in r`, `MsgBox cell.Value`.